# array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in include()

Tags: entities

I'm using the following to get the raw value of a field Drupal:

```
$foo = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_foo');
$foo_shift = array_shift($foo);
$foo_value = $foo_shift['value'];
```

Which works a treat but every so often I get the following error:

Warning: array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in include() (line 106 of ).

I think it might have somehting to do with checking the value is set as I only get it after going to a page where the value isn't set. But if I try to check 'field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_foo')' is set that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you mean by "that doesn't work"? The problem is likely because `field_get_items` returns FALSE if the field doesn't exist on that node. Checking if `$foo` is empty (using `empty`) should work.  So something like:

```
$foo = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_foo');
if (!empty($foo)) {
  $foo_shift = array_shift($foo);
  $foo_value = $foo_shift['value'];
}
```

Alternately, because `field_get_items` returns false when it doesn't have a value to return, you could just put the `$foo = ...` line in the if statement itself:

```
if ($foo = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_foo')) {
  $foo_shift = array_shift($foo);
  $foo_value = $foo_shift['value'];
}
```

The problem with `isset` is that it's just checking if the variable has a value attached to it. FALSE doesn't ping it as not being set, whereas FALSE is included in the list of values that are considered empty for `empty`.

The "Just to Remind" section of this posts: http://alexchernomaz.com/2014/10/14/php-empty-isset-is_null/ provides an excellent table of what values are considered empty/null/set for each function (`empty`, `is_null`, and `isset`), if you're interested in learning more.

Comment: Cool thanks that did the trick, used the second example, seemed the cleanest to me!

Answer (score 0):

Never assume an array  (or object) is filled. So after you retrieve an array or object (e.g. field_get_items) you always need to check if it has data before doing anything with that data.

In your case, your code would look something like this:

```
$foo = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_foo');
if (!empty($foo)) {
  $foo_shift = array_shift($foo);
  $foo_value = $foo_shift['value'];
}
```

I mostly use the magical [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function which checks if the variable exists, is not empty, is not NULL and is not 0.

Edit: Erin was a sec faster posting the answer, at least we're on the same page. ;)